# Why message in socketio backend return only other user message

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm using socket.io to build a chat room, but when input message, only other user see the message, the writer do not see any thing but other message like image above. This is my code :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;

//New imports
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");

const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`⚡: ${socket.id} user just connected!`);
  socket.on("join_room", (data) => {
    socket.join('123');
  });
  
  socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
    socket.to('123').emit("receive_message", `${socket.id}: ${data}`);
  });
  
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(": A user disconnected");
  });
});

app.use(cors());

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

[image]

And front end

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ConnectionState } from './components/ConnectionState';
import { ConnectionManager } from './components/ConnectionManager';
import { MyForm } from './components/MyForm';
import { socket } from './socket';
import { Events } from './components/Events';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

export default function App() {
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(socket.connected);
  const [fooEvents, setFooEvents] = useState<any>([]);
  const [joinRoom, setJoinRoom] = useState<{
    name: string;
    room: string;
    time: Date;
  }>();

  function onJoinRoom() {
    socket.emit('join_room', '123');
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function onConnect() {
      setIsConnected(true);
    }

    function onDisconnect() {
      setIsConnected(false);
    }

    socket.on('connect', onConnect);
    socket.on('disconnect', onDisconnect);

    return () => {
      socket.off('connect', onConnect);
      socket.off('disconnect', onDisconnect);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    function onFooEvent(value: any) {
      setFooEvents((previous: any) => [...previous, value]);
    }
    
    socket.on('receive_message', onFooEvent);

    return () => {
      socket.off('receive_message', onFooEvent);
    };
  }, [socket]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ConnectionState isConnected={isConnected} />
      <Events events={fooEvents} />
      <Button onClick={onJoinRoom}>Join Room</Button>
      <ConnectionManager />
      <MyForm />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Connection State is a text dispay connection state, events is where display message, only an array, Connection Manager is button to connect, MyForm is form input message and submit

Answer (score 0):

You should put message state into useEffect's dependencies.

```
useEffect(() => {
  function onFooEvent(value: any) {
    setFooEvents((previous: any) => [...previous, value]);
  }

  socket.on('receive_message', onFooEvent);

  return () => {
    socket.off('receive_message', onFooEvent);
  };
}, [socket, fooEvents]);
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not working. the same result like above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).